# Minimum of trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

Here's a problem that I got:

> Let $A, B$ and $C$ be real numbers such that
>
> (i) $\sin A\cos B + |\cos A\sin B| = \sin A |\cos A| + |\sin B| \cos B$,
>
> (ii) $\tan C$ and $\cot C$ are defined.
>
> Find the minimum value of $(\tan C − \sin A)^2 + (\cot C − \cos B)^2$.

My attempt:

I first tried expanding the whole expression:

\begin{equation}
 (\tan C − \sin A)^2 + (\cot C − \cos B)^2=\tan^2 C + \frac{1}{\tan^2 C} - 2(\tan C\sin A + \cot C\cos B) + \sin^2 A + \cos^2 B
\end{equation}

By (ii) we know that $C$ cannot be equal to $0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$ But then what do I do next? I have no idea where to use the first constraint.

Comment: HINT:

If $\cos A,\sin B>0$

$$\sin(A+B)=\dfrac{\sin2A+\sin2B}2=\sin(A+B)\cos(A-B)$$

$$\iff\sin(A+B)[\cos(A-B)-1]=0$$

If $\sin(A+B)=0,A+B\equiv0\pmod\pi$

Else $\cos(A-B)=1\implies A\equiv B\pmod{2\pi}$

But I believe: there should be some smarter way which can avoid  case by case analysis.

Comment: First constraint  shows $(\cos B-|\cos A|)(\sin A-|\sin B|)=0$ then $\cos B=|\cos A|$ or $\sin A=|\sin B|$ thus $\sin A\cos B>0$.